# glGetAttribLocation() returns -1 but the variable is uniform, How to fix it?

Tags: c++, opengl

This is my shader 'triangles.vert':

```
#version 430 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 vColor;
uniform mat4 vRota;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vColor;
    gl_Position = vRota * vPosition;
}
```

and this is the snippet of the C++ source:

```
ShaderInfo shaders[] = 
{
    { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert" },
    { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag" },
    { GL_NONE, NULL }
};

GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
glUseProgram(program);

//...

int vRota_loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vRota");

if (vRota_loc == -1)
{
    cout << "No uniform match for 'vRota'" << endl;
}
```

It returns -1, but I don't know why.

Am I doing something wrong in the shader?

ps `LoadShaders()` is function for compiling and linking the shader programm. it is given as sourcefile by a book I'm practicing with. So I supose there won't be the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`glGetAttribLocation` is for vertex attributes, i.e. `in` variables in the vertex shader (such as `vPosition`). You want `glGetUniformLocation`.

Answer (score 5):

A `uniform` is not an attribute. You need to use `glGetUniformLocation`

A `uniform` is consistent for each vertex while an `attribute` is per vertex.

Comment: Uniforms are also available in every shader stage, which makes them quite different from vertex attributes. They are program-wide constants.